# Constructor Method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have read the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) regarding the constructor method and what it can be used for as far as setting state and binding functions but is it really necessary in most cases?

What's the difference between doing

```
export default class MyClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            foo: 'bar',
        };
        this.member = 'member';
        this.someFunction = this.anotherFunction(num);
    }
    anotherFunction = (num) => num * 2;
    render() {
        // render jsx here
    }
}
```

and simply putting all that outside the constructor like

```
export default class MyClass extends Component {
    state = {
        foo: 'bar',
    };
    member = 'member';
    someFunction = this.anotherFunction(num);
    anotherFunction = (num) => num * 2;
    render() {
        // render jsx here
    }
}
```

Is one option preferred over the other and are there any performance issues I should know about? This has been bugging me for a bit and I can't seem to find a concrete answer out there.

Comment: The `foo = bar` syntax *outside* the constructor is not valid JavaScript, it's an experimental feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two examples are functionally identical, but the key thing is that assigning things outside of class methods, but inside of body of a class, like you have with everything other than `render` and `constructor`, is not standard ES6, and will only work via Babel. That syntax is the proposed [class property syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).

Comment: Right. I knew Babel was working its magic but wasn't quite sure what (if any) the tradeoffs were. Also I found [this article](https://medium.com/@joshblack/writing-a-react-component-in-es2015-a0b27e1ed50a) to be of some help. Thanks.